# FOR em php e sqlsrv

Tags: php, sql-server

Tenho que fazer um FOR em PHP, usando SQLSRV.
Estou usando a penúltima versão do PHP e não a última, pois não consigo atualizar o PHP.

Comment: Por favor tente explicar melhor o problema que tem e que quer resolver, e se possível mostrar o código onde tem esse problema e possíveis erros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Algo que se pode usar é o [sqlsrv_fetch_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

```
$sql = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM SomeTable";
$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
if( $stmt === false) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
}

while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          echo $row['LastName'].", ".$row['FirstName']."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Não Raphael. Preciso que seja via for para poder pegar os dados individualmente. Com while não consigo fazer isso, entende?
Ex: Preciso pegar umas 5 contas de email.

Comment: @GustavoSevero como o Raphael fez apanhas os dados individualmente. Experimenta.

Comment: Com o while você consegue ter individualmente os dados dentro da sua variavel $row. Que será um array associativo de uma linha do seu resultado sql.

então você será capaz dentro do while fazer algo como $row[email].

Caso você queira pegar 5 contas de email de uma tabela com 100 registro.
Utilize um limit na sua sql.

Ou use um break condicional para sair do loop.

Comment: E como farei para pegar $row[email][0], $row[email][1], $row[email][2]...? Pois estou usando uma classe do php, o phpmailer.

Comment: O seu sql irá retornar uma tabela com diversas linhas.

Comment: Oi Raphael, mas como coloco essas linhas no email?
Olha como fiz:
$mail->AddAddress($row['email'], $row['nome'])
Porém, em cada um deles deve ter mais de um email... Será que vai funcionar?
Gostari de te passar toda a classe para veres como posso inplementar. 
Valeu.

Comment: O seu sql irá retornar uma tabela com diversas linhas.
Quando você faz o while, em cada iteração, a variável $row irá conter uma dessas linhas. A variável $row['email'] irá, em cada iteração do wile apontar para o valor do email. Até que não existam mais linhas a ser percorrida.
No exemplo, digamos que você tenha 20 linhas com LastName e FirstName.
O while irá percorrer essas 20 linhas do sql e irá dar echo 20 vezes.

Você pode colocar dentro do loop while o envio do email com o phpmailer, assim, para cada linha do seu resultado sql ele irá enviar um email.

Comment: Seria algo como
while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          $mail->AddAddress($row['email'], $row['nome']);
}

Comment: Foi o que fiz... Olha como está parte do código:

'while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
          echo htmlentities($row['nome']).", ".$row['email']."<br />";


$mail->AddAddress($row['email'], $row['nome']);'

Comment: E qual foi o resultado?